# Using Java SimpleDateFormat to find max date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, maxdate

I haven't programmed in Java for many years, but I now have to change a program I wrote some time ago. In this program I need to read a QIF file and find the qif record with the maximum date (Dmm-dd-yyyy).
I could not get this to work in my program so I wrote a simple test to demonstrate the problem I am having. I think there are other ways to do this, like lists and collections. But I still want to know why using SimpleDateFormat won't work. Notice in the output that this method produces the max for July but seems to ignore all August dates.

### Thanks, Mike

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

```
class DateParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
        Date nextDate = null;
        Date maxDate = null;
        String nextStrDate = null;
        String maxStrDate = null;

        //Fill date array.
        String date[] = {"07-14-2014","07-22-2014","07-31-2014",
                         "08-01-2014","08-04-2014","08-06-2014"};

        try {
            //Start with early maximum date.
            maxDate = sdf.parse("01-01-1800");
            // Find Max date in array.
            for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
                nextStrDate = date[i];
                nextDate = sdf.parse(nextStrDate);
                if(nextDate.after(maxDate)){
                    maxStrDate = nextStrDate;
                    maxDate = nextDate;
                }
                System.out.println( "Next Date = " + nextStrDate);
            }
            System.out.println("\nMax Date = " + maxStrDate);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Got error:" + e);
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT

Next Date = 07-14-2014
Next Date = 07-22-2014
Next Date = 07-31-2014
Next Date = 08-01-2014
Next Date = 08-04-2014
Next Date = 08-06-2014

Max Date = 07-31-2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You format is incorrect, this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

because (per the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation),

> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
> ...
> M         Month in year           Month           July; Jul; 07
> ...
> m         Minute in hour          Number          30
> ```

Comment: Really need to get the `SimpleDateFormat` on fast dial in browser... +1

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)....

> m Minute in hour

What you want is

> M Month in year

Change `mm-dd-yyyy` to `MM-dd-yyyy`